# Insert rss pubdate to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I try to insert a rss pubdate to my MySQL database. The format of the date is:

```
Tue, 16 apr 2013 17:04:08 UT
```

I try different function to format this pubdate, but I have problems with the timezone UT in the date. Functions I tried:

```
strftime("%a, %d %b %G %H %M %S", strtotime($pubdate));
date_create_from_format('D, d M Y G:i:s U', $pubdate);
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What error(s) are you receiving?  What is the data type of the column you are trying to insert the pubdate into?

Comment: My date is saved in mysql under 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: When I execute the function below I get Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime. $date date_create_from_format('D, d M Y G:i:s', 'Tue, 16 apr 2013 17:04:08 UT');

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this for inserting pubdate from RSS feed into mysql DateTime field

```
<?php
function pubDateToMySql($str) {
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($str));
}

$pubDate = 'Wed, 29 Jul 2015 06:59:41 +0000';

$mysql_datetime = pubDateToMySql($pubDate);

echo $mysql_datetime ;
```

**Output**

```
2015-07-28 23:59:41
```

ref : http://www.timwickstrom.com/server-side-code/php/convert-rss-pubdate-to-mysql-datetime/

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to insert in to a mySQL DateTime field right?
so your goal is to get it to be in this format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

you can try this using [strptime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php):

```
$rssdate = "Tue, 16 apr 2013 17:04:08 UT";
$parsed = strptime($rssdate,'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'); 
$sqldate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime($parsed['tm_hour'], $parsed['tm_min'], $parsed['tm_sec'], $parsed['tm_mon']+1, $parsed['tm_mday'], 1900+$parsed['tm_year']));
```

after that you should have gotten $sqldate with a value of

```
2013-04-16 17:04:08
```

take note that the `UT` will be discarded because of the DateTime field not being able to handle it. If you really need it, then just change your row into a String type if you can.

Another thing, i tried using the `date_create_from_format` too but it seems that it cant recognize the month of April as 'apr' since in the format it needs to be capitalized like 'Apr'.